# Minimizing the Variance in Compressed SGD

Tags: machine-learning

I have been reading this paper [[1]](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9439935) and [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.11028). There is a statement that reads as follows:

> The variance between compressed gradient and uncompressed gradient must be made as small as possible because this way it has been shown that the learning is accelerated.

I infer that in general the smaller the variance of gradient in SGD, the faster the convergence. How can we prove this statement?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/524236/relationship-between-variance-of-gradient-and-sgd-convergence

Comment: Yes, it's sufficiently similar.